# Archiving historical email sends - retrieving the exact copy of the email sent

Tags: marketing-cloud

I would like to know if there is a way to Archive historical emails? We have a request from the legal team to extract the exact copy of the email sent to the user. I was able to figure out a way to Archive the current and future sends but we are yet missing the historical data.

I'm sure I can pull it from the _click dataview only if user clicked on 'View_email_url' cta. Presumably, only a small set of audience would click on it, doing this way I might loose majority of the information.

Is there any way I can get this working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SFMC does not store rendered messages so you will be unable to go back and get these emails.

Answer (score 2):

As @EazyE commented, SFMC by default does not store the resulting messages when you complete a send.  These messages are rendered, queued into Mail Agent and then sent out to the recipient and finally purged from the system.

The only way to store these messages is to purchase the Archiving service inside SFMC, use CC/BCC to an archive mailbox, or build your own archiving system.  These would not account for any historical sends, but only for those sends in the future.

The only real way to gather these sends is if the email and data for them have not changed, you can recreate them via Send Previews or the API and store them. You can also use any collected VAWP link, but remember that when the VAWP link is clicked, the AMPscript/SSJS is rendered anew, so if there is a 'current date' field (Now()) or the data has changed, then this new info will be displayed - not the original email.